# Does Android automatically convert numbers to local alphabet?

Tags: java, android, numbers

I have an app that generates numbers. I want to localise for China.

I have code that looks like this:

```
this.diceValueTextSwitcher.setText("" + (rand.nextInt(6) + 1));
```

Where diceValueTextSwitcher is a text field.

I will not need to localise the numbers for Europe and North America (and other countries that speak European languages) as all major European languages (except Russian?) use the Arabic number alphabet (0...9). However, Mandarin and Cantonese do not.

If my Android phone is set to Cantonese or Mandorin language, will Android automatically convert the arabic numbers into  equivalents? Or is it Java that does this? Or would it not happen at all? If so, is the best way to localise this to have Strings of Mandorin (or whatever) characters that are swapped in/out in the normal fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't automatically convert for you, no. The main reason is probably that the numbering system doesn't work exactly the same. Yes, it's a decimal system, but there are individual characters for ten, hundred, thousand, ten thousand, etc. It's not a one-for-one character swap. So, if it *did* convert one-to-one, it wouldn't make sense to a native reader.

For example, with Arabic numerals, to write twenty-three, you do:

```
(two)(three)
```

In Japanese, you'd write:

```
(two)(ten)(three)
```

I wouldn't worry about it, though. The Arabic numbering system is taught in schools in Asian countries, and they use it extensively for most things involving a lot of numbers. Price tags, accounting, games, gauges, anything like that.

If you really *do* want to localize, you'll have to do it manually, with the correct strings, or find a conversion function.

*Disclaimer:* This is based on my living in Japan for a few years, but I'm almost positive China is the same. They use a lot of the same ideograms, including the numbers.